# Need Excel VBA Guidance

Tags: vba, excel

The issue I am looking to solve:
I want to look at one column which is automatically populated with a due date.  My organization wants to enforce an In-House due date of two business days (M-Th) prior.  To automatically populate the In-House due date with the 2 days prior according to day in the week the actual due date falls on, I have written this Sub:

```
Sub In_House()

Dim In_HouseDue
Dim CurrentCell

CurrentCell = Range("D3").Value

Select Case CurrentCell

Case Weekday(CurrentCell) = 1
In_HouseDue.Value = DateAdd("d", 5, CurrentCell)
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Case Weekday(CurrentCell) = 2
   In_HouseDue.Value = DateAdd("d", 5, CurrentCell)
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Case Weekday(CurrentCell) = 3
In_HouseDue.Value = DateAdd("d", 2, CurrentCell)
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Case Weekday(CurrentCell) = 4
In_HouseDue.Value = DateAdd("d", 2, CurrentCell)
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Case Weekday(CurrentCell) = 5
In_HouseDue.Value = DateAdd("d", 2, CurrentCell)
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Case Weekday(CurrentCell) = 6
In_HouseDue.Value = DateAdd("d", 3, CurrentCell)
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Case Weekday(CurrentCell) = 7
In_HouseDue.Value = DateAdd("d", 4, CurrentCell)
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

In_HouseDue = Range("E3").Value

End Select

End Sub
```

It runs without any error, but it does not actually populate the In-House due date column that starts with Cell "E3"

Any help would be great!

Comment: This really runs without error? YOu haven't `Set In_HouseDue` as a range variable, and Variant types do not have a `.Value` property.

Comment: @David Zemens - note that each Case expression resolves to a Boolean - hence none of the In_HouseDue.Value are evaluated at run time.

Comment: @rskar yep, I eventually did notice that, hence my answer below :) good catch!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what PowerUser says, redo your `Select Case` block, like so:

```
Select Case Weekday(CurrentCell)

Case 1
In_HouseDue = DateAdd("d", 5, CurrentCell)
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Case 2
   In_HouseDue = DateAdd("d", 5, CurrentCell)
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think that last line should be the other way around.  Try

`Range("E3").Value=In_HouseDue`

Comment: It should also be after the `End Select`. And actually, the `Select Case` block is all wrong.

Comment: @rskar, I agree. Missed that.

Comment: Also, what is `In_HouseDue`? It's declared as Variant type, but syntax is refering to it like a Range (e.g., `InHouse_Due.Value`), yet I don't see it assigned with a `Set InHouse_Due` anywhere in this code.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Your `Select Case` statement was wrong, also your variables were improperly declared, which will often cause errors, or otherwise undesired results.

```
Sub In_House()

Dim In_HouseDue As Date
Dim CurrentCell As Date

CurrentCell = Range("D3").Value

    Select Case Weekday(CurrentCell)

        Case 1
            In_HouseDue = DateAdd("d", 5, CurrentCell)
             ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        Case 2
           In_HouseDue = DateAdd("d", 5, CurrentCell)
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        Case 3
            In_HouseDue = DateAdd("d", 2, CurrentCell)
             ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Case 4
            In_HouseDue = DateAdd("d", 2, CurrentCell)
             ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Case 5
            In_HouseDue = DateAdd("d", 2, CurrentCell)
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Case 6
            In_HouseDue = DateAdd("d", 3, CurrentCell)
             ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Case 7
            In_HouseDue = DateAdd("d", 4, CurrentCell)
             ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    End Select

    Range("E3").Value = In_HouseDue

End Sub
```